Not part of CF standard, will not be supported by CF Error message
I am trying to use the merge function in QGIS on 6 aerial rasters. When I try to merge them I get an error.
Is there a workaround to this? I would like to merge the 6 singular raster files to just one raster file.
All aerial rasters are in byte- 8 bit unsigned integer format.
The full error can be found in the attached image:

Warning 1: projection name Oblique_Stereographic in not part of the CF standard, will not be supported by CF!

Full error text i get:

Warning 1: projection name Oblique_Stereographic in not part of the CF
standard, will not be supported by CF! Traceback (most recent call
last):  File
"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.7\apps\Python312\Scripts\gdal_merge.py", line
14, in  sys.exit(main(sys.argv)) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  File
"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.7\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py",
line 650, in main return gdal_merge(argv)  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File
"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.7\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py",
line 635, in gdal_merge fi.copy_into(t_fh, band, band, nodata,
verbose) File
"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.7\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py",
line 348, in copy_into return raster_copy(  ^^^^^^^^^^^^  File
"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.7\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\gdal_merge.py",
line 117, in raster_copy t_band.WriteRaster(  File
"C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS33~1.7\apps\Python312\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py",
line 7864, in WriteRaster return _gdal.Band_WriteRaster(self,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  RuntimeError: OUTPUT.nc, band 1:
IReadBlock failed at X offset 0, Y offset 12500: netCDF chunk fetch
failed: #-39 (NetCDF: Operation not allowed in define mode)  May be
caused by: netCDF chunk fetch failed: #-39 (NetCDF: Operation not
allowed in define mode)  May be caused by: netcdf error #-62 : NetCDF:
One or more variable sizes violate format constraints .  at
(C:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.9.0\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::SetDefineMode,2988)
Exception ignored in: 
RuntimeError: netcdf error #-62 : NetCDF: One or more variable sizes
violate format constraints .  at
(C:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.9.0\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::Close,2947)
May be caused by: netcdf error #-39 : NetCDF: Operation not allowed in
define mode .  at
(C:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.9.0\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,5811)
May be caused by: netcdf error #-39 : NetCDF: Operation not allowed in
define mode .  at (C:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.9. Process returned
error code 1



This seem to be a projection error did you reproject your rasters ? are they all in the same CRS ?

You appear to have shown a warning message, not an error, so you may be looking in the wrong place to solve the problem.  What are the errors reported, in red in your image.  Please copy the text to question

Are the input rasters in NetCDF format, or do you definitely need NetCDF as output, or would GeoTIFF or something else be OK?

GeoTIFF will suit my needs perfectly fine. It doesn't need to be in NetCDF format, Raster Merge is the function i'm using. All rasters are in the same CRS, all 28992 Amersfoort RD New.

What do you see in the "GDAL/OGR Console Call" box?

This is what i see in the console call: gdal_merge.bat -ot Float32 -of netCDF -o C:/Users/luukf/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YrSzwj/b71e487ee11a4fac8f4e19d748bfc080/OUTPUT.nc --optfile C:/Users/luukf/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_YrSzwj/8e5dbb44010147d1b616b715adcd14cd/mergeInputFiles.txt

Try to make it show -of GTiff instead of netCDF that gets now selected. I believe you can do it by selecting "Save to file" instead of the default "Save to temporary file". With the "Save to file" dialogue you can select the output format.

I did this and it resolved the issue. Thank you so much all for the assistance.
